# jquery event being called once for each time the modal is opened

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, event-handling

I have a bootstrap modal form that contains a list of items to be tracked. There is a toggle all box that selects/unselects all items in the list if checked. The jquery function is called once for each time I show the modal which I do not understand.
Open the modal the first time, jquery function is called.
Open the modal the second time, jquery function is called twice.
Open the modal the third time, jquery function is called three times.
And so on.
Why is this checkbox function called once for each time I open the modal? Does jquery push things onto some type of stack somewhere?
What I want to be able to do is pop an alert if the user selects all items to be checked. But I don't want him/her to get multiple alerts. Code below:

```
$('#realTimeModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var modal = $(this)
  console.log('controller-1253: realTimeModal handler');

  //first, clear out any previous layers
  clearLayers();
  console.log('show_realtime, updatePositions: ', updatePositions );
  clearInterval(updatePositions);

  /*
   * Check to see if the 'Toggle All' checkbox is checked. If so
   * either select all checkboxes or deselect them.
   */

  $("#check_rt").change(function () {
    console.log('==================================');
    console.log('=====     in #check_rt   =========');
    console.log('==================================');
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    if (checked == true) {
      $.each($("input[class='form-check-input callSign_checkbox-rt']"), function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
      });
      trackAll = 'true';
    } 
    else {
      $.each($("input[class='form-check-input callSign_checkbox-rt']"), function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
      trackAll = 'false';
    }
    //if ( trackAll == 'true' )
      //alert('If you select all aircraft, breadcrumbs will not be displayed.');
  }); 
}) // $('#realTimeModal').on('show.....)
```

What I want to be able to do is simply pop up the alert if the user checks the select all checkbox. But I only want one alert, not as many alerts as times the modal has been opened. Am I missing something fundamental to jquery here?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an event handler each time the modal is opened.

The function -

```
$("#check_rt").change(function () { ... }
```

is defined inside the -

```
$('#realTimeModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { ... }
```

This should not be the case. You should call the `$("#check_rt").change()` outside of modal show function call.

Comment: I moved the $("#check_rt) outside the modal handler, and now the check for toggle all is not called at all when I click/unclick the toggle all checkbox. :(

Comment: No. that was my mistake. Thanks!